# Creating a user in phpmyadmin detached from mysql

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I want to create a user in phpmyadmin which is detached from the mysql database. Is this possible?

Comment: phpMyAdmin does not have users, nor is it a DBMS, its a tool written in PHP!

Comment: What do you actually mean by detached from the database

Answer (score 1):

When you click "Add user", it allows you NOT to create a db (just choose "NONE")

See the pic below

[image: see this]